# mysql database no longer receiving data after addition of .htaccess file?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

So I have some data that is sent to a database, and it worked well at one point, nothing changed at all except the addition of an .htaccess file, when I inspect the page to see whats happening I see:

```
NULL
Invalid query:
```

my php file that points to my database with my credentials is :

```
<?php

$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password');
mysql_select_db('mydatabase', $dbc);

?>
```

and the file that sends the data:

```
<?php
include('/path/to/fileabove.php');

function mysql_insert($table, $inserts) {
    $values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($inserts));
    $keys = array_keys($inserts);

    return mysql_query('INSERT INTO `'.$table.'` (`'.implode('`,`', $keys).'`) VALUES (\''.implode('\',\'', $values).'\')');
}

// get the table name
$tab = $_POST['table'];

// decode the data object from json
$trials = json_decode($_POST['json']);

// get the optional data (decode as array)
$opt_data = json_decode($_POST['opt_data'], true);
$opt_data_names = array_keys($opt_data);

var_dump($trials);

// for each element in the trials array, insert the row into the mysql table
for($i=0;$i<count($trials);$i++)
{
    $to_insert = (array)($trials[$i]);
// add any optional, static parameters that got passed in (like subject id or condition)
    for($j=0;$j<count($opt_data_names);$j++){
        $to_insert[$opt_data_names[$j]] = $opt_data[$opt_data_names[$j]];
    }
    $result = mysql_insert($tab, $to_insert);
}

// confirm the results
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} else {
    print "successful insert!";
}

?>
```

and in my `error_log` file I see:

```
PHP Warning:  array_keys() [<a href='function.array-keys'>function.array-keys</a>]: The first argument should be an array in /path/to/savedata.php on line 33
```

after some searching I found this post:

http://galleryproject.org/node/57633

so I tried adding that to the .htaccess file and then i inspected it and it looks like my host went ahead and altered it:

```
# File modified on Wed Sep 14 16:28:37 2016 by server
# For security reasons, mod_php is not used on this server. Use a php.ini file for php directives
# php_value session.cookie_domain http://mydomain
```

Not sure what else to do ??

Comment: First, you should not use mysql, but mysqli or pdo instead. mysql is going away. As for troubleshooting, what do you see if you do `print_r($_POST);`? If that looks reasonable, what does `$opt_data` look like. If that's not reasonable, what does `json_last_error` tell you?

Comment: Also, I'm pretty sure people could do mischief with your query by sending bogus keys in the options array. You might want to white-list the keys that are acceptable.

Comment: You mentioned that everything worked until an .htaccess file was added. Maybe that says there is something in that file causing the problem? What was the purpose of adding the file and what is the content of the file?

Comment: @Jerry something looks off if I print $_POST, I'm getting a format like: `\"\\\"rt\\\",\\\"responses\\\",\\\"` all around. I've looked at this before but didn't see the \\\ characters

Comment: @Chris the .htaccess file has the minimum for password protecting a directory. I added it because I only want some users to be able to access the task that is on the directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that adding the `.htaccess` file triggered some change in the php configuration to set magic quotes on, which is what resulted in the `\"\\\"rt\\\",\\\"responses` format. After switching to php 5.6, which no longer supports magic quotes, the data saves correctly and there is no longer a problem